# Manually add groups in ggplot2 object (operate on ggplot2 object as a list)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this `ggplot2` object:

```
library(ggplot2)
count <- data.frame(y = LETTERS[1:5],
    x1 = rep(0, 5), 
    x2 = c(3, 5, 6, 4, 3))

aplot <- ggplot(count) + geom_segment(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, 
    y = y, yend = y), size = 3)

## view the object as a list
library(qdap)
lview(myplot)
```

And the plot looks like this:

[image]

I want to manually add 2 more groups (F & G; `new <- c("F", "G")` but they have no corresponding data, just empty.  I will do this many times in a look for the purpose of an animated plot.  It's very efficient to alter the ggplot object rather than re-render it each time.  So the final output would look like this:

[image]

Again I want to operate on the ggplot2 object itself (`aplot` here) as a list and alter an individual element to add empty groups to the plot.  Obviously I could alter the data and re-feed it to the original plot.  I'm not interested in that but in acting on the ggplot2 object itself.

Comment: It isn't the same as altering the ggplot2 object as a list, but you can add geoms to an existing ggplot2 object. If you use ggplot() without any arguments, in each geom statement you provide a data argument. It would be easy to create a data frame new with "G" and "F" and set their x1 and x2 to any number and then use aplot + geom_segement(aes(...), size = NA, data = new). Is this along the lines of what you are looking for?

Comment: Just to be explicit, is `new_data <- data.frame(y = LETTERS[6:10], x1=0, x2=0)` 
`aplot + geom_segment(aes(x = x1, xend = x2, y = y, yend = y), data=new_data, size=0)` a good solution? You can also operate directly on `aplot$data`: `aplot$data[6:10, ] <- new_data; aplot`, but that's a bit of an overkill for me since it is a low-level manipulation.